# How do I copy a file to new folder based on File name and date with powershell

Tags: powershell, copy

Hope someone can help, I'm new to PowerShell an can't seem to get this working the way I want.

I'm trying to create a PowerShell script to run every morning to check in a folder for a file that was created that morning, the file will have a creation date of the day before, for example `2022-04-20_test.csv`

The list of files can grow in the folder so I only am trying to copy over the one file that was created in the morning with the previous days date on it.

The script I've been testing copies the file over but is not checking the date correctly so every file in the folder called `*_test.csv` gets moved.

is there a way of me checking the file name with the previous days date or checking when the file was created date?

```
$EarliestModifiedTime = (Get-Date).AddDays(-1)
```

I thought this would check for all yesterday  only files.

Any help or suggestions would be gratefully received. thanks

```
$DestinationFolder = "c:\test1"
If(!(test-path $DestinationFolder))
{New-Item -ItemType Directory -Force -Path $DestinationFolder
}
$EarliestModifiedTime = (Get-date).AddDays(-1)
$Files = Get-ChildItem "c:\test\*_test.csv" -File
foreach ($File in $Files) 
{
if ($File.LastWriteTime -gt $EarliestModifiedTime)
{
    Copy-Item $File -Destination $DestinationFolder
    Write-Host "Copying $File"
}
else 
{
    Write-Host "Not copying $File"
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to identify the files by the date embedded in their *names*, use the following:

Note: I'm assuming you want just yesterday's file(s) in this example:

```sh
# Get yesterday's date in a format such as "2022-04-20"
$yesterdaysPrefix = (Get-Date).Date.AddDays(-1).ToString('yyyy-MM-dd')

Copy-Item -WhatIf "c:\test\${yesterdaysPrefix}_test.csv" -Destination $DestinationFolder
```

<sup>Note: The [`-WhatIf` common parameter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_commonparameters#whatif) in the command above *previews* the operation. Remove `-WhatIf`  once you're sure the operation will do what you want.</sup>

Note:

- The `.Date` property returns the *very start* of the current calendar day (i.e., midnight). Its use isn't strictly necessary here, given that the format string (`'yyyy-MM-dd'`) doesn't contain a time-of-day component.
- However, use of `.Date` becomes important if you want to use `[datetime]` instances directly (rather than strings) for comparison, such as against files' `.LastWriteTime` properties, in order to cover the *entire calendar day* - see below.

---

As for **what you tried**:

- `$EarliestModifiedTime = (Get-Date).AddDays(-1)` isn't the *start* of yesterday (midnight), but the same time of day as when you run this command; therefore, it's better to use `$EarliestModifiedTime = (Get-date).Date.AddDays(-1)`
- Due to use of `-gt`, `if ($File.LastWriteTime -gt $EarliestModifiedTime)` also includes all of *today's* files.

  - Either: Use `$File.LastWriteTime.Date -eq (Get-Date).AddDays(-1).Date` to limit matching to yesterday's files.
  - Or:  Use `if ($File.LastWriteTime -le (Get-date).AddDays(-1).Date)` - i.e. the `-le` operator (less-than or equal) operator rather than `-gt` (greater-than) - to match all files last written yesterday *or before*.

Comment: thank you kindly that worked perfectly, and thank you for explaining in detail its really helped my understanding cheers.